# How to gernerate Stubs for PolicyEntitlementAdminService in WSO2IS

Tags: wso2, policy, stub, wso2-identity-server

The question:
How to gernerate Stubs for PolicyEntitlementAdminService in WSO2IS?

I customized the Web Service Api and now I'd like to gerneate a stub class. Is there any tutorial regarding to wso2?

Thanks

Comment: did you tried default way..?  

http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/creating-web-service-client-3-steps-using-eclipse/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the Stubs generated in a common method to use. You can refer [1] for the purpose.
Otherwise the relevant WSO2 service stub for the specified component resides at [2], where you can replace the relevant wsdl and generate the stubs.

[1] - http://pushpalankajaya.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-convert-wsdl-to-java.html

[2] - https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/service-stubs/org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.stub/4.2.0